# google pie chart not showing up on a modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am trying to Display a google chart on a Modal Popup. It works just fine on a normal page, But it does not appear on the Modal.

This is the code I am using. I am not sure what is going wrong.

## this is the HTML  and JS code that lives on a url, /polls/

```
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<h3 style="text-align:center;">Test</h3>
<hr>
<div id="chart_div" style="height: 500px;">
</div>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Options', 'Votes'],
        ['1',     11],

        ['2',      2],

        ['3',  2],

        ['4', 2],

        ['5',    7],

        ['6',    21],
      ]);

      // Set chart options
      var options = {
                      'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
                      'is3D': 'True',
                      'legend':'bottom',
                      'width':'100%',
                      'height':'100%',
                      chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"80%"}
                    };

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
```

## This is the html button that lives on page /home/

```
<a class="open-newmodal" href="/poll/">show poll</a>
```

So the idea is, that using a modal and jquery's .load() function, I should be able to load the chart that lives on /poll/ page to my /home/ page in the modal that I made.

This is the modal I am using

## Modal Css

```
.newmodal-container {
    display: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.newmodal {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    border:1px solid #D3D3D3;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #D3D3D3;
}
.dp-none {
  display: none !important;
}
.dp-block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

## Modal JS

```
// New Modal
var body = $('body'),
main = $('.main'),
open_modal = $('.open-newmodal'),
close_modal = $('.close-newmodal'),
modal_container = $('.newmodal-container');
open_modal.live('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  body.addClass('body-locked');
  modal_container.addClass('dp-block');
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  modal = $('.data-load');
  modal.load(href);
  modal.attr("title",href);
});
close_modal.live('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  body.removeClass('body-locked');
  modal_container.removeClass('dp-block');
  modal.empty();
});
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27){
    event.preventDefault();
    body.removeClass('body-locked');
    modal_container.removeClass('dp-block');
    modal.empty();
  }
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're drawing it on page load, have you tried delaying the drawing until the modal is displayed?

Comment: @NuclearGhost I am not sure how to do that. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @NuclearGhost I tried the delay() function as well. It doesnt seem to work

Comment: I was thinking not to initialize and render the pie chart until the button is clicked to display the modal.  I sometimes have issues with google maps where it won't display on a modal until the modal is visible

Comment: @NuclearGhost I am sorry but I am not sure how to do that. :( I've been reading the documentation, and the only thing I could think of was delay() but even that doesnt seem to work. And I guess, the problem is what you are suggesting. I inspected the elements and saw that the rest of the stuff except the javascript was getting loaded to my modal when I use .load()

Comment: Is there some kind of z-index issue going on possibly?

Comment: @ColinPear I dont think that is the problem. When I use inspect element and check the contents of the modal, I cannot see any javascript being loaded in it. So somehow when I use .load() to add the piechart on my modal, somehow the JS isnt loading on the modal.

Comment: Can you update your question with the HTML you are using? As it stands, your code works but it does not include the popup so I can't repro the issue.

Comment: @nick_w please have a look at the updated code and content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, seeing as how you want to load another page as a modal graph, I have the following solution.

Initialize your google lib on the parent page as in http://jsbin.com/abucet/3, then make sure your child page doesn't re-initialize or re-include the libs that are loaded in the parent page, see child @ http://jsbin.com/ajerol/5/edit

So basically the child page @ http://jsbin.com/ajerol/5
Parent Page accessing child @ http://jsbin.com/abucet/3

Parent Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>


<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>


  <div id='headerDiv' style='background-color:#FF0000'>
      Test Load
  </div>

  <div id='modalDiv' style='background-color:#FFAA00'>
      Close this and click the button to load 

      Graph will be in a modal JQuery Dialog.  Some of the google visualization initialization will be done in this page, not the page we're loading.
  </div>

  <button id='getIt'>Get the Graph</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
$('#getIt').click( function() {
      $.get( "http://jsbin.com/ajerol/4",
        function(data) {
             var newGraph= "<div id='graphModal'>"+data+"</div>";
             //clean up html
             newGraph.replace('<body>','');
             newGraph.replace('</body>','');
             // we have the libs on this page, no need for that other cruft       
          newGraph.replace('<head.*head>','');
          // debug: 
          //alert(newGraph);
            // append to the current modal
            $('body').append(newGraph);            
            //  the graph page in modal 
            $('#graphModal').dialog({modal:true,width:300});
            $('#getIt').parent().append('<button onclick="$(\'#graphModal\'\).dialog(\);">showGraph</button>');
        }
      );
});

// initial note
$('#modalDiv').dialog({modal:true});

// load this on the parent page, not the one we're calling
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
```

Child Page

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }





    </script>

<div id="modal_chart" class="modal">
  <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
  <div id="chart_div" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Child Javascript (on load)

```
drawChart();
```

Comment: So perhaps you can modify your _modal.load(href);_ to either use jQuery's ajax call or switch out for my example using _.get_ that uses a callback and some string replaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that might explain a little of what I meant from my comments.

Basically when the button is clicked to show the chart, that's when you'll do the loading for the pie chart.

Hope this puts you on the right track.

```
<button onclick="displayModal">Show Chart <\button>

<div id="modal_chart" class="modal">
  <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
  <h3 style="text-align:center;">Test</h3>
  <hr>
  <div id="chart_div" style="height: 500px;">
  </div>
</div>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function displayModal() {
    $("#modal_chart").fadeIn(fast, function() {
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    });
}

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Options', 'Votes'],
    ['1',     11],

    ['2',      2],

    ['3',  2],

    ['4', 2],

    ['5',    7],

    ['6',    21],
  ]);

  // Set chart options
  var options = {
                  'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
                  'is3D': 'True',
                  'legend':'bottom',
                  'width':'100%',
                  'height':'100%',
                  chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"80%"}
                };

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. Even on the regular page I am not sure why, but this approach is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there should be any explicit issues with loading the chart and then applying the modal code.  Here's an example using some of the CSS you mentioned and JQueryUI alternatives http://jsbin.com/ajerol/3 (you can also actively edit the code here http://jsbin.com/ajerol/3/edit ).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }


    function displayModal() {
      $("#modal_chart").show();
    }

    function hideModal() {
      $("#modal_chart").hide();
    }

    function makeModal() {
      $("#modal_chart").addClass('newmodal-container');
      modal_container = $('.newmodal-container');
      $("#modal_chart").show();

    }

    function jqueryModal() {
      $("#modal_chart").dialog({ modal: true });
    }





    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <button onclick="displayModal()">Show Chart </button>
    <button onclick="hideModal()">Hide Chart </button>
    <button onclick="makeModal()">Attach modal CSS </button>
    <button onclick="jqueryModal()">jQuery modal </button>



<div id="modal_chart" class="modal">
  <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
  <h3 style="text-align:center;">Test</h3>
  <hr>
  <div id="chart_div" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;">
  </div>
</div>

  </body>
```

One question about your code, are you calling the following code prior to the html loading?

```
open_modal = $('.open-newmodal'),
close_modal = $('.close-newmodal'),
modal_container = $('.newmodal-container');
```

Comment: yes the code works perfectly fine by the time the loading happens on the same page. But when I use .load() function to load the piechart that lives on a different page, nothing shows up. Please have a look at my updated question, I've tried to explain it more in the question itself

Comment: I saw your updated question and updated my example, though I noticed that if you are going to separate your pie-chart from the main page, it is advantageous to load the google library in the main page; instead of the child-page.  The example I added works, though it was quicker for me to add it in with a JQueryUI dialog. See my comments related to example http://jsbin.com/abucet/3

Comment: I am so sorry I had completely forgotten about your response. But yes, you are right, all I had to do was add google.load and the main google js file into my mainpage and then it worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can use google charts from remote url with modal like this:

On **remote url** you need to load google link in this way :

```
enter code here

$.getScript( 
"https://www.google.com/jsapi",
   function() {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart'],"callback": drawChart});
 });
```

Worked for me.